# converganceof n.w^n a.s, p, m.s

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm learning about convergence but I keep getting confused when trying to find if something converges without specifying a limit.

**For example $X_n = n*\omega^n$, $\omega$ belongs to (0,1]. Does $X_n$converge a.s., p., m.s?**

I found that it doesn't converge a.s to 0 because $p(n*w^n < \epsilon)$ doesn't equal 1 as $n-> \inf$ . And not in probability because $p(n*w^n >= \epsilon)$ isn't 0 as n-> inf. But I don't know how to find if it converges to anything else

Answer (score 0):

If $0<t<1$ then $n t^{n}$ does tend to $0$.

If your random variables are defined on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure then $n\omega^{n} \to 0$ for  every $\omega$. Hence the convergence (to $0$) holds almost surely, in probability and in distribution. But $\int_0^{1} (n\omega^{n})^{2} d\omega=\frac {n^{2}} {2n+1} \to \infty$ so the sequence does not converge in mean square.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without relying on Lebesgue measure? When I used the definition,  I got that it doesn't converge to 0 a.s or in probability.

Comment: You need a probability space  to define random variables and convergence almost surely, in probaility etc.

Comment: Could you show me How to prove this using the definition of convergence a.s? For Xn to converge almost surely to 0, p(n∗w^n < ϵ) must equal 1 for all $\epsilon > 0$, for all n> m as n-> inf. 
p(n∗w^n < ϵ) < p (n∗w^n < ϵ) for n = m, m+1 ...N  = p(n∗w^n < ϵ) for n = m * p(n∗w^n < ϵ) for n = m+1 *…* p(n∗w^n < ϵ) for n = N. Some of those are gonna be less than 1. Thus, p(n∗w^n < ϵ) <1. Thus, the sequence doesn't converge a.s. 

Where did  I go wrong with this?

Comment: $p(n\omega^{n} >\epsilon)=p(\omega >( \frac {\epsilon} n)^{1/n}=1-(\frac {\epsilon} n)^{1/n}$ You have to use  the fact that $(\frac {\epsilon} n)^{1/n} \to 1$ to conclude that $p(n\omega^{n} >\epsilon) \to 0$.